# filenotfoundexception while trying to read file from internal storage of android phone

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I am new to android and trying to copy file from internal storage of the phone to byte array. Following is the code.

Java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView path;
    TextView status;
    Button browse;
    Button clear;
       private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        path = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Path);
        status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Status);
        browse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Browse);
        clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Clear);


        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                path.setText("Cleared");

            }
        });
        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
                        path.setText(FilePath);
                        File file = new File(FilePath);
                        FileInputStream fin = null;
                        fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte barr[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
                        fin.read(barr);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        status.setText(ex.toString());
                    }
                }

                break;

        }
    }


}
```

AndroideManifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ncryptn">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It gives me filenotfoundexception. When I try to display the path which is captured in String FilePath, it shows correctly.

I have added the permissions for storage.

Comment: Before reading the files first make sure you have the permission to Read Internal/External storage.

Comment: I have added the permissions as well, I have posted the code. Please let me know if anything needs to changed.